# UILabel intrinsicContentSize crashes on iOS 12

Tags: iphone, uilabel, ios-autolayout, ios12, intrinsic-content-size

I'm updating my app to iOS 12 and in my subclass of UILabel, I'm getting a crash when I call

```
super.intrinsicContentSize
```

Commenting out the code leads to a crash at layoutSubviews(), presumably the next time it would query intrinsicContentSize.

I'm currently overriding it and the app runs just fine, but my labels are the wrong size.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had an attributed string that previously set the whole length to use no underline. In my migration I changed it to

`attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value:[], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length))`

I don't think it liked the empty array, despite that being what it  specifically told me to change it to.